# Accessing a inner div value in javascript, with no ids to help

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following structure

```
<div onClick="javascript:Myfunction('value');">

<div title="Mytitle"> </div>

</div>
```

Can I access in the javascript Myfunction, the title of the inner div.
There are no ids here.

Comment: you need an id somewhere, or at least to know a little more about the page to do this.

Comment: The Myfunction() is in my control I can send 'this' out there, can this help ?

Comment: Is there only one child for the div with onclick?

Comment: sorry I was late, Yes there is only one child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to change the html code then you can use this.

```
function MyFunction ( elem )
{
      var child = jQuery(elem).find("div");

      alert ( child.attr("title") );
}


<div onclick="MyFunction(this);">

<div title="Mytitle"> </div>

</div>
```

Otherwise try this

```
$(document).ready ( function () {           
                $('#divMain').click(function() {
                    var titleElem = $(this).find("div");                    
                    alert ( titleElem.attr("title") );                  
                });
            });

<div id="divMain" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
                <div title="Mytitle">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The previous answer solves my problem, thanks.
The second solution uses div ids, and I dont have the id attr in the divs.

Comment: The hypertext is generated by a calendar displaying library, I dont have much control on it. But I have a option to provide the javascript when a use clicks on a cell in the calendar

Comment: ok, then continue with the first block of code. **Good luck...**

Answer (score 0):

If it's the only div with the title you can use this selector:

```
$('div[title]')
```

The easiest solution would to add a class or id to the div with `onClick` defined (I suggest moving onlick to JS code as well)

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div title="MyTitle"> ... </div>
</div>
```

And in JS:

```
$('.myClass').click(function() {
    MyFunction('value');
});
```

Then you can find inner div with

```
$('.myClass div')
```

Comment: You missed a single quote in the MyFunction('value');

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you use any JavascriptLibraries like jQuery. If you do, you can select your objects via CSS selectors, which would be in your case

```
$('div[onclick] > div[title]')
```

You'd get your inner DIV element with it. If there are more elments that match this criteria, you could limit them even more by attribute values.

Comment: will the div[onclick] select all the divs with onclick attribute in it?